# How to get length of getElementsByTagName with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Working through some example code to sort a list of  within a :

```
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("timelineul");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("figcaption");
    //Loop through all list items:
    console.log(b);
    console.log(b.length);
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item:*/
      console.log(b[i].innerHTML);
      console.log(b[i+1].innerHTML);
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /*if next item is alphabetically lower than current item,
        mark as a switch and break the loop:*/
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done:*/
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

console.log(b); produces this:

[image]

but,
console.log(b.length); results in 0

How can I get the number of items in b so I can iterate through them to sort my figures by figcaptions?

[image]

Comment: `document.getElementById("timelineul").length` ??

Comment: @marekful Seriously?

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue might be due to `getElementsByTagName()` returning a **live NodeList** which you're then manipulating, but it is 6am and time for me to sleep (yup). Try getting the list with `querySelector()` instead.

Comment: We cannot reproduce this. Can you add the rest of your code if any related to this portion?

Answer (score 3):

This situation happens when your javascript starts executing before the html is loaded. If that is the case, then you might have to wrap the call to the sortList() function within a DomContentLoaded event like so :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    sortList();
});
```

Comment: I tried replacing the call with this but now it never calls the sortList function.  Where should it go?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Bala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365095/8379720), mostly because I am unable to reproduce your issue:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('a');
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName('span');

console.log(spans.length);
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <ul>
    <li><span>hi</span></li>
    <li><span>yo</span></li>
    <li><span>dude</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```